# Show iOS user that Enterprise app is installing

Tags: ios, deployment

I'm distributing an enterprise iOS app via a webpage with manifest.plist and all that. I'm fielding a lot of complaints where the user thinks that the app is not installing because after clicking the button and getting the expected "...... would like to install ..... [Cancel/Install]" window, nothing appears to be happening. The app really is installing but the user is looking at the webpage and needs to switch to the right panel of the iOS home screen to see the app icon.

After installing an enterprise (or AdHoc) iOS app, how can I take the user to the screen where it is installed?

Comment: Its not possible with iOS. You could use page where you show the user brief instructions on what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is an official way to navigate the user to a page on the home screen from within a webpage.

I would try to use a [URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) to launch your enterprise app following installation. This will then demonstrate to the user that the app has been installed. I am unsure how iOS will respond to this if the developer hasn't yet been trusted.

Otherwise, another solution is an educational one. The landing page for downloading the enterprise app could include a few steps and possibly an animation showing someone installing the app, closing the browser and seeing the app has been installed, and then navigating to the trust settings.

Of course, using an MDM would mean the app can be pushed to the phone and updated without the need to the user to navigate into the trust settings. Services like [SimpleMDM](https://simplemdm.com/2016/03/14/how-to-enroll-in-mdm-with-apple-configurator-2/screen-shot-2016-03-14-at-10-46-58-pm/) provide a range of enrolment interfaces such as QR code, sms of a link, and Apple Configurator 2. The devices wouldn't need to be supervised, and all users are still prompted to agree to installing the app, etc.

Comment: I'd first have to confirm it had finished installation, and that they had gone through the Settings->General-Device Management->Trust step.